# commit on master and detail on F10 pressed

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have master and detail on my form. When I want to enter a record I do it in detail block. No  data to enter on master. On master is automatic counter and simple data for status. So when I enter data into detail block and hit F10... I need master to be saved too. But master says no changes to save.

Comment: Why do you need the master to be saved if there are no changes to save?

Comment: there are autonumber (generated by function) and status indicator (fixed value at enter) to be saved, but when I enter new line in master and then enter data in detail block and when hit F10 for commit... detail is commited but master status stay at "NEW" and wont commit, but it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the master record updated, e.g. the autonumber or status indicator, you need to make sure that *something* is changed on the master record - you need the record status to be set to `CHANGED`.

It might be as simple as putting a when-validate-record trigger on the detail block which updates a master record item (e.g. set it to the same value).

However, I'd also look at the code which is setting your master "status" field, and ask why it is not already setting the record status to `CHANGED`. Maybe your existing code is in the wrong trigger.